# Is there a method to list the open windows in /usr/bin/screen to the terminal?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

TLDR: Is there a way to list screen windows to text via some screen option?

First, some background.

I am logging in to a linux server via SSH through Windows RDP. This is an automated login via CyberArk.

Please, don't ask why I'm doing this, that is the only available method. I don't like it any more than you do :)

Due to some setting of the terminal (I cannot change any settings), the usual CTL-A +W does not show me anything.

screen -ls shows screen sessions.  I want to see a list of the windows open in my current screen session.

I have searched for a method to list the windows as text, but have not found anything.

Likely the collective wisdom of superuser can help out.

EDIT: The output of CTL+A W simply does not appear on the terminal.

Comment: It would help to know what terminal you are using for your text window.  Just saying `rdp` is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

`screen -Q windows` seems to do what you want.

You don't say why <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> doesn't work for you, but both the activation key (via escape) and the display method (via hardstatus) can be changed.

For example, `hardstatus firstline` should make the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> output show up as the top line on the screen.  `hardstatus message` should do something similar, but without reserving a line for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however screen -Q windows does the same as CTL+A W.
The problem is that the output does not appear on the terminal.  I do not know why it does not work. 
The environment is highly regulated, and I cannot do anything to change it.

Comment: `screen -Q windows` should output to stdout as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that just a few moments ago.
It does work, I didn't realize it was sending output to stdout as well.
I will try it ASAP in the troublesome environment, and see if it works there as well.